# Create custom type without mysql table

Tags: mysql, laravel

for a project i'm working on i need to be able to create custom objects that are persisted to database.
The software use laravel+mysql.
Here's an example:
the person who uses the software need to add a new type of item that he can sell to his customers. This item has its own properties (name, size, etc..). I would like that he can create a new "type" from the software interface without creating a new mysql table.
Is it possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) to serialize objects and keep them as JSON.

You can store this data in a column with `JSON` or `TEXT` type.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/migrations#columns

Comment: Ok,but this way can i make a query against thousand of rows?

Comment: If you need to search DB for some unified column, like `user_id` or `status`, you can add this data as column instead of adding it to JSON.

Comment: What about they're not unified column like price or description?

Comment: You mean some of the objects will have `price` and others will not? How are you going to search by price anyway? If all properties aren't unified you will not be able to search by those because your app knows nothing about all these properties.

Comment: Yes, the properties are unified, my mistake. I mean: this way i need to create a new column for each properties. I want that the user can create the new type using the web interface.

Comment: I'm using laravel migrations and this way i need to create a new migration by code every time.

Comment: Let user create he's own properties, but require to enter some unified ones. If you want to search items by `price`, make user enter this property and store it as separate column. Then serialize all non unified data and store it as JSON. In this case you will not need to create new migrations or tables.

Comment: Ok, i get it. But how can i search the rows for one of the non-unified properties? Thanks for your time

Comment: You'll not be able to do that. How can you know what custom property user will add? You can create some kind of list of all properties used by users, but I doubt you'll want to search by those.

Comment: You're right. I got the idea for the custom type from Drupal, where you can do this.

Comment: My problem is this: this software will be used by different people each one with mostly the same software but with some different data types. I would like to keep a shared codebase beetween all the installations.